# delete duplicate records leaving 1

Tags: sql, merge, duplicates

I did this `MERGE` statement to get all unique item numbers from my two tables:

```
MERGE INTO  XXINV.XXINV_ITEM_SNAP_EGS_E5A6 ISE
USING apps.XXRPT_INV_VALUATION_D535_V IVD
ON (IVD.ITEM_NUMBER = ISE.ITEM_NUMBER)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (ORGANIZATION_CODE, ITEM_NUMBER)
VALUES (IVD.OWNING_ORG_CODE,IVD.ITEM_NUMBER)
```

But the problem is there are duplicate item numbers in the `IVD` table but not in the `ISE` table so how can I get rid of the duplicates(leaving 1) that came with the merge.

NOTE I'm very new to sql. 
Im using Toad for Oracle 10g

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like you can specify a subquery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) for the `USING` clause in an Oracle `MERGE` statement, so you may be able to do something like:

```
MERGE INTO  XXINV.XXINV_ITEM_SNAP_EGS_E5A6 ISE
USING (select distinct ... from apps.XXRPT_INV_VALUATION_D535_V) IVD
ON (IVD.ITEM_NUMBER = ISE.ITEM_NUMBER)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (ORGANIZATION_CODE, ITEM_NUMBER)
VALUES (IVD.OWNING_ORG_CODE,IVD.ITEM_NUMBER)
```